# Interop with Javascript libraries (I.e. NPM package AWS Amplify)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, dart, interop, flutter

I want to interact with AWS services through a Flutter app, specifically through [AWS Amplify library](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify) (Although I'm open to other recommendations).

I'd like to manage authentication with Cognito and call various AWS Lambda functions. This is very easy to do if I can interact with the library, but very difficult if I can't!

I know Dart has [js interop](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/js/0.6.1/) and [NodeJS](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/nodejs_interop/0.9.0/) interop packages, but their examples are bit opaque. The examples look like it generates Dart code (to use as a library) from JS, but the docs look like it just allows us to call Javascript functions from within Dart.

How can I do this?

Comment: Dart-js-interop is only relevant for Dart compiled to JS and run in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter, dart isn't compiled to javascript. So you can't use [js interop](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/js/0.6.1/) and similar in the client side.

So what you're asking is not possible

Comment: is there any way we can use npm packages in flutter app ? @Rémi Rousselet

Comment: For the newly added web-platform, maybe. For mobile, no.